# The kernel of a map from the integers to a symmetric group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \to S_n$ be a homomorphism, where $\phi(1)$ is some element in $S_n$.

1. Will $Ker(\phi)$ always be $|\phi(1)|\mathbb{Z}$, where $|\phi(1)|$ denotes the order of the element? If so, why?
2. If 1. is true, does this mean that for some element $g \in S_n$, $g^{|g|} = id$ always holds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to question 1 is yes, because for any $m\in\mathbb{Z}$,
$$\begin{align*}
m\in\ker(\phi)&\iff \phi(m)=0 & \text{ definition of kernel}\\\\
&\iff\phi(1)^m=0 & \phi\text{ is a homomorphism}\\\\
&\iff |\phi(1)|\;\text{ divides }\;m & \qquad{\text{a basic property regarding}\atop\text{orders of elements in groups}}\\\\\\\\
&\iff m\in|\phi(1)|\mathbb{Z} & \text{definition of }|\phi(1)|\mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}$$
Note that **nothing about this depended on the codomain of $\phi$ being the group $S_n$**.

The answer to question 2 is also yes, but really ... what do you think the definition of $|g|$ is?

Comment: Naturally, I forgot about that last point you made.

Answer (score 0):

For #2, since the element g belongs to a symmetric group of order n, any element from the same group would have order n. Hence, g^|g|= identity of the symmetric group of n.

Comment: Is that true? What about the element $(1,4,2,6)(2,5,7)$ in $S_8$? Isn't that of order 6?